# Link to Reddit is broken in the Help Center article on harassment

Tags: bug, status-completed, help-center, broken-link

The Help Center article [How do I report harassment?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/harassment) contains the following footer:

> Thanks to [Twitter](https://support.twitter.com/articles/20169998#) and [Reddit](https://reddit.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205701155), whose articles on harassment were helpful in creating some of the phrasing on this one.

However, the link to the Reddit article seems to be broken. Can this be fixed?

A copy of the old article is [saved on the Web Archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20181130114549/https://reddit.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205701155). It appears that the URL has been updated and moved to [this link](https://www.reddithelp.com/hc/en-us/articles/360043071072) (thanks to [@rene for fishing it out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353175/link-to-reddit-is-broken-in-the-help-center-article-on-harassment?noredirect=1#comment1180404_353175)), based on the matching title.

Comment: Was it this page: https://www.reddithelp.com/hc/en-us/articles/360043071072 ?

Comment: @rene The title matches, based on the [Web Archive link](https://web.archive.org/web/20181130114549/https://reddit.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205701155).

Answer (score 4):

This should be fixed now.

I've gone ahead and replaced the broken Reddit link with [the updated URL](https://www.reddithelp.com/hc/en-us/articles/360043071072) that [rene](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/158100/rene) linked to in the comments.